# how to I revert my solutions to resolve the conflicts?

Tags: java, android, git, github

I have made a few changes, then pulled from git.

I have had merge conflicts after pulling from git.

I have resolved these conflicts, but my app doesn't work as expected.

How can I revert my solutions (undo) conflict resolution?

I'm using 'egit', and 'source tree'

btw, what is a recommended conflict resolver tool?

Comment: Get fresh version from git again would be time efficient solution (assuming you don't have any new fixes apart from conflict resolution).

Comment: So you resolved the conflict, but did it wrong.  Now you want to get the conflict back so you can resolve it again?

Comment: I am assuming that you did not commit after resolving conflicts. You can abort the whole merge process using `git merge --abort` and go back to the state prior to git pull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `git merge --abort` to abort the whole merge process and take the repo to the state prior to merging.

Comment: how can I abort merge of a specific file and then re pull this specific file?

Answer (score 0):

`git reset --hard HEAD~1` will put your code and git repo both back to where they were before the last commit, which is probably the merge commit. Then you can try merging again.

If you don't care about the changes you had, you can always nuke everything local and start with a fresh `git clone`.

Comment: i didn't understand. I didn't do merge commit yet, as I have had conflicts